# Problems creating an executable file with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable

I want to generate an executable from a python file using pyinstaller, i need something which can be used on windows and hopefully on ubuntu. The generated dist folder containing all the executables is created with the command line:

> pyinstaller --debug=all gui.py

It creates gui (the executable file) using the gui.py file.

Doing ./gui the output is:

```
....
File "ssqueezepy/configs.py", line 150, in <module>
File "ssqueezepy/configs.py", line 107, in _get_gdefaults
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pietro/Desktop/ClaraGui/dist/gui/ssqueezepy/configs.ini'
[12263] Failed to execute script 'gui' due to unhandled exception!
[12263] LOADER: OK.
[12263] LOADER: Manually flushing stdout and stderr
[12263] LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
clear builtins._
clear sys.path
clear sys.argv
...
```

There are no other errors in the output (sometimes i read "a name of a lib" not found in PYZ). There is a way to fix the error above? What is the config.ini file requested?

Otherwise, there are other possibilities to achieve the same result? In the end I just need an executable which can be used on windows, generated from the code in python on ubuntu.

EDIT: I solved the issue deactivating the virtual environment and installing outside of it the dependencies. It's not a fix but it works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to open command prompt and drag exe into it and press enter, that way you will catch the error (if there is any) and then update your question, more info == more help.